# setPeekHeight() in java not giving same result as in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, bottom-sheet

I am working with Bottom Sheets in my app.

```
<include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/layout_book"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        />
```

This is my bottom sheet and when I change peek height from this xml to 120dp I get the proper view.
But when try to do same from java then I get different result i.e. height is lesser than that from xml.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(120);
```

Ideally it should not have been like this. I have no clue regarding this.
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you are not actually passing `120dp` to that method call. What exactly are you passing?

Comment: @BenP. I am passing 120 as int value was the required argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setPeekHeight()` (and many other size/dimension related methods) take in *pixel* values for their arguments. That means you need to convert your dp value to px first. The best way to do this is to define a `dimen` resource value and then grab it in code:

```
<dimen name="peek_height">120dp</dimen>
```

```
int peekHeightPx = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.peek_height);
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeightPx);
```

Alternatively, you can use `DisplayMetrics` to do the calculation yourself:

```
int peekHeightPx = (int) (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 120);
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeightPx);
```

Comment: Just now I got the solution.

Comment: bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(R.dimen.peek_height); did work too. Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't work. `R.dimen.peek_height` is a int, so it should compile, but the value of that int could be something totally random. Unlike e.g. `TextView.setText()`, there's no method built into `BottomSheetBehavior` that resolves resource ids.

Comment: But that is working flawless. May be that dimen tag compile it to some appropriate int value. I dont know whether two of those values could be same or not

Comment: I am literally weak in android concepts.